# How to create lists within lists in JavaScript using Pure DOM and Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

[How My List Should Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exULO.png)

I am trying to create multiple lists within another list using pure DOM and vanilla JavaScript using an array of objects that I have been provided.

**Array of Objects**

```
var directory = [
{ type: 'file', name: 'file1.txt' },
{ type: 'file', name: 'file2.txt' },
{
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'HTML Files',
    files: [
        { type: 'file', name: 'file1.html' },
        { type: 'file', name: 'file2.html' }
    ]
},
{ type: 'file', name: 'file3.txt' },
{
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'JavaScript Files',
    files: [
        { type: 'file', name: 'file1.js' },
        { type: 'file', name: 'file2.js' },
        { type: 'file', name: 'file3.js' }
    ]
}
];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stackoverflow works best when you ask about a **specific problem**. It isn't a good place for questions asking for vague help writing a complete application, even if it is a small one.

Comment: Hello new contributor! I honestly hate to down-vote new contributor questions, but your question is completely unclear. Can you clarify as to what the inputs are and what the output you are seeking is, as well as give us more information on what problem in javascript / with the DOM you are having? If you can do this, I will happily remove my downvote, okay?

Comment: I think you have the object well, you want an other thing or what's wrong?

Comment: My guess is that it appears the OP wants to use the provided array to produce DOM UL->LI nested structures as they appear in the image. But an attempt is required for usre.

Comment: So i have been given a bunch of object instances in the array of objects. Some object instances need to be prints as lists under another list. For Example, as seen by the picture, the 'files.name' instance is presented as a list under the name instance. I have tried creating the list many times but it only prints a single list.                                                                                                          
 MY TRY: var dr = document.getElementById('dir');


for(var a=0; a < directory.length; a++)
{
    dr.innerHTML += '<li>' + directory[a].name + '</li>';
}
}

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859730/making-dropdown-menu-with-multidimensional-array) will help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you tried, and describe how it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursive function and dom element creater `createElement()` function

```js
var directory = [{type: 'file', name: 'file1.txt' }, { type: 'file', name: 'file2.txt' }, { type: 'directory', name: 'HTML Files', files: [{ type: 'file', name: 'file1.html' }, { type: 'file', name: 'file2.html' } ] }, { type: 'file', name: 'file3.txt' }, { type: 'directory', name: 'JavaScript Files', files: [{ type: 'file', name: 'file1.js' }, { type: 'file', name: 'file2.js' }, { type: 'file', name: 'file3.js' } ] } ];


function creater(arr) {
  var str = '';
  var last="";
  arr.forEach(function(a, b) {
 
    var ul = document.createElement('UL')
    var li = document.createElement('LI')
    if (a.files) {
      if (a.name) {
        li.innerHTML = a.name;
        last =li;
      }
      last.append(ul)
      ul.innerHTML = creater(a.files);
      str += last.outerHTML;
    } else {
      li.innerHTML = a.name;
      last = li;
      str += li.outerHTML;
    }
  });
  return str
}

document.body.innerHTML = creater(directory);
```

```css
li ul{
 list-style-type:circle;
}
```

Comment: whats the point of str = ' '; Like whats the points of it being an empty string? Thanks for ur answer!!

Comment: yes .initially str declare as empty.becuse without empty its not match any condition .Its return `undefined` that why

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function.

```js
var directory = [{
    type: 'file',
    name: 'file1.txt'
  },
  {
    type: 'file',
    name: 'file2.txt'
  },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'HTML Files',
    files: [{
        type: 'file',
        name: 'file1.html'
      },
      {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'file2.html'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'file',
    name: 'file3.txt'
  },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'JavaScript Files',
    files: [{
        type: 'file',
        name: 'file1.js'
      },
      {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'file2.js'
      },
      {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'file3.js'
      }
    ]
  }
];
let list = '';

// recursive function 
function createList(array) {
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.type === 'file' && !item.files) {
      // template literals
      list += `<li>${item.name}</li>`
    } 
      // check if the files is an array then call the recursive function 
      else if (item.files && item.files.length > 0) {
      list += `<li>${item.name}</li>`
      createList(item.files)
    }
  })
  return list;
}
document.getElementById('liContainer').innerHTML = createList(directory);
```

```html
<ul id='liContainer'></ul>
```